# Laravel mix resource path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, webpack, laravel-mix

I have two Themes in my Laravel app, first one is a default page theme and the second is for the admin panel.

I would like to make separated assets folder for each, so I have created a configuration doing so. JS and CSS files are now landing in the appropriate directories, however I can't figure out how to do the same for fonts/images assets as they still land into my `public` directory.

What I want is:

Resource files from `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` to land in the `assets/fonts` or `assets/images`.

Resource files for my admin theme from `resources/themes/admin/default/assets/sass/app.scss` to land in the `admin/assets/fonts` or `admin/assets/images`.

How can I achieve this?

My .mix configuration file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath('public');
mix.setResourceRoot('../')

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'assets/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'assets/css');

// Admin assets

mix.js('resources/themes/admin/default/assets/js/app.js', 'admin/assets/js')
    .sass('resources/themes/admin/default/assets/sass/app.scss', 'admin/assets/css');

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason as to why you want your assets outside the public directory?